# Jmeter-Springboot-Mysql-ec2 Hikari connection pool - Connection not available

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to perform Jmeter testing for a rest api built using spring boot micro service and JPA.

The API connects to a Mysql instance executes couple of queries in parallel (async) and provide the result in JSON format.

Mysql Instance is deployed in aws.

It works fine for upto 10 users. If I increase it more , then I get connection not available .

```
engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

The only property I have configured in application.properties is connectionTimeout  (This property controls the maximum number of milliseconds that a client (that's you) will wait for a connection from the pool. If this time is exceeded without a connection becoming available, a SQLException will be thrown. Lowest acceptable connection timeout is 250 ms. Default: 30000 (30 seconds))

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout: 80000 (80 seconds).

I read about HikariCP and found that
maximumPoolSize: default: 10.
minimumIdle : Default: same as maximumPoolSize
maxLifetime: Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)

I am trying various combination of the properties mentioned above to  test for 100 concurrent users at a time.

Can some one tell me which properties of connection pool to tweak in order  to test this for 100 users? Or what is the optimum configuration ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: MaximumPoolSize should definitely help. But looks like your properties are not considered by the application. You have set the timeout to 80 s, but the log still says it is waiting only for 30 seconds.